# How to construct an in-memory virtual file system and then write this structure to disk

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystems, virtualfilesystem, pyfilesystem

I'm looking for a way to create a virtual file system in Python for creating directories and files, before writing these directories and files to disk.

Using [PyFilesystem](https://github.com/PyFilesystem/pyfilesystem) I can construct a memory filesystem using the following:

```
>>> import fs
>>> temp_dir = fs.open_fs('mem://')
>>> temp_dir.makedirs('fruit')
SubFS(MemoryFS(), '/fruit')
>>> temp_dir.makedirs('vegetables')
SubFS(MemoryFS(), '/vegetables')
>>> with temp_dir.open('fruit/apple.txt', 'w') as apple: apple.write('braeburn')
... 
8
>>> temp_dir.tree()
├── fruit
│   └── apple.txt
└── vegetables
```

Ideally, I want to be able to do something like:

```
temp_dir.write_to_disk('<base path>')
```

To write this structure to disk, where `<base path>` is the parent directory in which this structure will be created.

As far as I can tell, PyFilesystem has no way of achieving this. Is there anything else I could use instead or would I have to implement this myself?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`fs.copy.copy_fs()`](https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/reference/copy.html#fs.copy.copy_fs) to copy from one filesystem to another, or [`fs.move.move_fs()`](https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/reference/move.html#fs.move.move_fs) to move the filesystem altogether.

Given that PyFilesystem also abstracts around the underlying system filesystem - [`OSFS`](https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/reference/osfs.html) - in fact, it's the default protocol, all you need is to copy your in-memory filesystem ([`MemoryFS`](https://docs.pyfilesystem.org/en/latest/reference/memoryfs.html)) to it and, in effect, you'll have it written to the disk:

```
import fs
import fs.copy

mem_fs = fs.open_fs('mem://')
mem_fs.makedirs('fruit')
mem_fs.makedirs('vegetables')
with mem_fs.open('fruit/apple.txt', 'w') as apple:
    apple.write('braeburn')

# write to the CWD for testing...
with fs.open_fs(".") as os_fs:  # use a custom path if you want, i.e. osfs://<base_path>
    fs.copy.copy_fs(mem_fs, os_fs)
```

Comment: Good answer. `copy_fs` accepts FS objects and FS URLs, so the following would also work: `fs.copy.copy_fs(mem_fs, '.')`

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to stage a file system tree in memory, look at the [`tarfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html).

Creating files and directories is a bit involved:

```
tarblob = io.BytesIO()
tar = tarfile.TarFile(mode="w", fileobj=tarblob)
dirinfo = tarfile.TarInfo("directory")
dirinfo.mode = 0o755
dirinfo.type = tarfile.DIRTYPE
tar.addfile(dirinfo, None)

filedata = io.BytesIO(b"Hello, world!\n")
fileinfo = tarfile.TarInfo("directory/file")
fileinfo.size = len(filedata.getbuffer())
tar.addfile(fileinfo, filedata)
tar.close()
```

But then you can create the file system hierarchy using `TarFile.extractall`:

```
tarblob.seek(0) # Rewind to the beginning of the buffer.
tar = tarfile.TarFile(mode="r", fileobj=tarblob)
tar.extractall()
```